# react-native-webview opening safari on iOS

Tags: react-native

I have upgraded my project to

- *React 18.2.0*
- *react-native to 0.69.1*
- *react-native-webview ^11.22.7*

But react-native-webview from the package (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) open the uri directly on safari while on android it open correctly a webpage inside the application.

Does anyone face the same issue ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove WebView

```
originWhitelist={['intent://']}
```

**Props**, if Added.